# data structures access by index

Tags: c++

-Vectors
Linked Lists
Maps
Stack

It is little confusing, when it says access, I did not quite understand what it meant. Started thinking about data structures , I know that arrays are indexed. Also know that vector can be accessed by index, but access by index? I think that got me confused

Comment: You first: Which do you think, and why? Related, your answer is "B-Tree" ? Interesting, because that isn't one of the four options you listed. From what hat did *that* rabbit emerge?

Comment: Why would you think you couldn't access elements of a `vector` by index??

Comment: Well, to be honest question is little confusing, when it says all access, I did not quite understand what it meant. Started thinking about data structures , I know that arrays are indexed. Also know that vector can be accessed by index, but all access by index? I think that got me confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory, in c++:

- `std::vector`,
- `std::string`,
- `std::array`,
- `std::deque`,
- `std::bitset`,
- `std::valarray`,
- `std::span` (Not a container)

So the answer is "Vectors"-ish.